# Need to Find Number of DropDown Options which are not selected

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Need to Find Number of DropDown Options which are not selected.

> URL : http://output.jsbin.com/osebed/2
>
> TASK:
>
> 1. Select Even Option available in fruits (Banana and Orange)
> 2. Find out number of option not selected (Apple and Grape)

I tried it and could able to print Selected options (Banana and Orange) but cannot able to print Not Selected options (Apple and Grape)

**Code:**

```
public class Ques12 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        ChromeOptions options = new
        ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        driver.get("http://output.jsbin.com/osebed/2");
        WebElement Fruits = driver.findElement(By.id("fruits"));
        Select select = new Select(Fruits);
        select.selectByIndex(0);
        select.selectByValue("orange");

        List < WebElement > list = select.getOptions();
        List < WebElement > selectedOptions = select.getAllSelectedOptions();

        for (WebElement i: selectedOptions) {
            for (WebElement j: list) {

                if ((j.getText()).equals(i.getText())) {
                    System.out.println("Selected option " + j.getText());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not selected option " + j.getText());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Selected option Banana
Not selected option Apple
Not selected option Orange
Not selected option Grape
==========================
Not selected option Banana
Not selected option Apple
Selected option Orange
Not selected option Grape
```

Comment: My Task is 

URL : http://output.jsbin.com/osebed/2

TASK: Select Even Option available in fruits (Banana and Orange)
      Find out number of option not selected (Apple and Grape)

-------
I tried it and could able to print Selected options (Banana and Orange) but cannot able to print Not Selected options (Apple and Grape)

My output:
Selected option Banana
Not selected option Apple
Not selected option Orange
Not selected option Grape
Not selected option Banana
Not selected option Apple
Selected option Orange
Not selected option Grape

Comment: Hi, please edit your question including the HTML code. It will help to create a minimal reproducible example. Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Doing that, you have more chances to get an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic below in your code is wrong

```
List<WebElement> list = select.getOptions();
        List<WebElement> selectedOptions = select.getAllSelectedOptions();

        for (WebElement i : selectedOptions) {
            for (WebElement j : list) {
```

Simply use isSelected()and go through complete list only once to check for isSelected and print accordingly

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        driver.get("http://output.jsbin.com/osebed/2");
        WebElement Fruits = driver.findElement(By.id("fruits"));
        Select select = new Select(Fruits);
        select.selectByIndex(0);
        select.selectByValue("orange");

        List<WebElement> list = select.getOptions();
        for (WebElement j : list) {

            if (j.isSelected()) {
                System.out.println("Selected option " + j.getText());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not selected option " + j.getText());
            }
        }
        driver.quit();
```

Should Print

```
Selected option Banana
Not selected option Apple
Selected option Orange
Not selected option Grape
```

Comment: Thanks a Ton Abhay chaudhary , i have no idea about isSelected(). Code works perfectly now!